# Android marker bitmap change on zoom change

Tags: android, google-maps

I had implemented few customised markers in my project.The thing i need is that on zoom change these marker's icon should change to a different from default one .Also reaching default zoom it should come back as before.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this might help, you just need to specify at wich zoom levels should markers change

```
    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
                                    private float currentZoom = -1;    
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                                        if (cameraPosition.zoom != currentZoom) {
                                            currentZoom = cameraPosition.zoom;
                                             ...
                                             your code
```

Comment: If i am using a cluster manager and markers are added to this. What should i do to change the marker icon

Comment: well, i am not very familiar with maps utility library, but there is a demo project in wich you can find activity with custom markers

Comment: when doing such athing as u have mentioned UI is hanging.